# Want to upgrade my Inspiron 7520 to Ubuntu 14.04 But Dual Video Cards is a Problem

Tags: upgrade, 14.04, ati, inspiron, hybrid-graphics

I have Inspiron 7520. Rig is:
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-3612QM CPU @ 2.10GHz × 8,
RAM: 8GB, Graphics: Intel HD 4000 (cpu), AMD Radeon 7730M (gpu) under 64bit OS.
My problem here is switchable graphics. I have [Certified Ubuntu 12.04.1 for Inspiron 7520](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201203-10678/) installed on my laptop computer and it works great. I just want to upgrade to Ubuntu 14 but when I tried it, hybrid graphics became problem. I installed  drivers (from both AMD's Catalyst and Intel's), tried all three additional drivers in system settings but it had no use for me, I even couldn't turn brightness off. Then I used some "Terminal-> sudo gedit" stuff but it caused to fail to detect video, input devices etc, so I live-booted Ubuntu and undid sudo-gediting. My point is that, everything in Google didn't work so I reinstalled Certified Ubuntu. As I understand, dual-graphics (or "hybrid video") is still a problem for over 2 or 3 years (not only in Ubuntu), but when Dell wanted to solve it, they solved it. And I do not want to get tired. So my question is, what should I do with hybrid video and desire of Ubuntu? Should I wait for Ubuntu 12.04 to notify me that there is 14.04, or what should I do?